# Convert a variable into a string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a simple question. Suppose that I have this code:

```
y <- x 

name <- "x"
```

Where `x` could be any R object.

Is there an a way the variable `name` to automatically take the string `x` once I assign `x` to `y` ?

Comment: What is the motivation for this? Why can't you simply execute both lines of code at the same time? Without background info this is hard to answer because the code you provided already does what you want, so how to fix it?

Comment: To expand on @Fnguyen’s comment, this sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1968). What do you *actually* want to accomplish?

Comment: My code is around 500 lines ... y is defined in the beginning, and then somewhere else in the code I want to put the string x. So, instead of assigning the string `x' by looking on the code, I want to make it automatic, so once I assign it to y, the other object, `name` will be automatically defined.

Comment: @msh855 Now you’ve just moved the problem: *why* do you need the `name` variable? And how is it tied to `y`?

Comment: it is not tide. And I need the variable name -- because i work with other programs who use the `name` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the value of `x` to be assigned to `y`, while the variable name itself to be assigned to `name` as a string. If so, then you can capture `x` as an unevaluated expression, then 1) evaluate it and store the result to `y`, and 2) deparse it and store the resulting string to `name`:

```
z    <- quote(x)    # z contains unevaluated expression `x`
y    <- eval(z)     # evaluates the expression, returning the value of x
name <- deparse(z)  # returns the expression as a string
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to get the name of the variable that was assigned to `y` then one cannot do that perfectly but a heuristic would be to examine every variable and return the name (or names) of anything with matching value.

If the code you are using is within a function and you are looking for variables that are defined in that function then use `e <- environment()` in place of the line that defines `e` below.

```
# test data
# start a fresh R session
a <- 1
x <- 2
y <- x

e <- .GlobalEnv
setdiff(names(Filter(isTRUE, eapply(e, identical, y))), "y")
## [1] "x"
```

### Note

If the question is how to get value value of `x` from its name then:

Use `get`:

```
# test input
x <- 3
name <- "x"

y <- get(name)
y
## [1] 3
```

This will also work if `x` is in the global environment:

```
y <- .GlobalEnv[[name]]
y
## [1] 3
```

Comment: not exactly what I am looking. This seems to do the opposite of what I want. I want name to the string 'x', not its value or values

Answer (score 0):

Would that work for you? I personally would not use anything like this in my scripts, but it accomplishes what you need:

```
assign_and_save_name <- function(new_var, var, var_name){
  var_value <- sapply(ls(envir = parent.frame()), get)[[var]]
  assign(new_var, var_value, parent.frame())
  assign(var_name, var, parent.frame())
}

x <- 3
assign_and_save_name('y', 'x', 'name_x')
```